# How do I make the "value" of the <input type="radio"> invisible?

Tags: javascript, css, templates

```
<input type="radio" value="1" id="baby">
```

I'd like to keep this code like that.
However, can I apply a CSS to it so that the "1" is not displayed to the user?

Edit: For some reason, it is being displayed, I don't know why.
I do have a CSS attached to it though.

Comment: I do not understand the question. The "value" is not displayed anyway!

Comment: If it is being displayed then you'd better validate your HTML. Maybe some attribute is "leaking"

Comment: Just a note: whenever using web markup, you should attempt to target XHTML instead of HTML, for conformance with XML standards.  In this case, it means explicitly terminating your entities: <input type="radio" value="1" id="baby" />

Comment: Just a note: whenever using web markup,  you should atteempt to target HTML instead of XHTML, since Internet Explorer doesn't support XHTML so you have to jump through hoops to make it look like HTML, and the effort simply isn't worth it for most authors.

Comment: David Dorward and Dathan...well, who is right!?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The value of "1" is not displayed to the user at all, it's hidden and only has meaning when the form posts. You need to add a `<label>` tag or just raw text near the radio button to display the value you want the user to see.

Comment: Preferably a label since that is (a) semantic (b) makes this easier for screen reader users (c) gives a large click target for mouse users

Comment: True on every count. `<label>` is preferred.

Answer (score 2):

For radio buttons, the *value* attributed is never rendered by the user agent (unless it does something rather weird). Typically, if you need a radio button with a label, you explicitly specify one, ideally using the <label> tag.

Answer (score 1):

The "1" should not display for the user.. it's just a value..

Normally, you'd declare a radio input like so:

```
<label><input type="radio" value="1" id="baby"> Baby </label>
```

This will make "Baby" the label for the radio button, this will also make clicking on the Baby text activate the radio button, which is what accessibility rules would require..

Comment: I believe the correct usage is: `<input type="radio" value="1" id="baby"><label for="baby">Baby</label>` (the `id` and `for` elements must match)

Comment: Yes, yes! To @intgr you listen! Do not put `<input>` tags inside `<label>` tags! Doing so violates many doctypes.

Comment: Does it? Which ones? Consider:

http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#idx-label-1

Comment: @Randolpho Yes, which ones, never had any problems with it

Comment: @alex: my first thought was "that's just HTML 4 transitional, XHTML will be stricter on it". But I went and checked, and holy crap, I was totally wrong. I've been doing XHTML strict for years now and always thought label could not accept an input tag. I humbly offer apologies to you and Ben.